# requests are not sent to ngnix reverse proxy in docker compose

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am new to docker / dev ops world. So please excuse me. I have a docker compose file and ngnix config as shown below

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  risk-analysis-XXXX1:
    image: c360saascr.azurecr.io/risk-analysis-XXXX1:1118_ra_in_java
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "9010:9010"
    links:
      - ngnix-server
    command: -Xms12g -Xmx12g -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=8 -Dapi.connectTimeout=60 -Dapi.readTimeout=60 -Drisk.analysis.service.indexNameDictionaryMatchCounter=id_clients1 -Dlogging.level.com.classify360=DEBUG -Drisk.analysis.XXXX.hostName=ngnix-server -Drisk.analysis.XXXX.port=5001 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=heapdumps -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=0.0.0.0 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9010  -jar risk-analysis-XXXX-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar


  risk-analysis-XXXX2:
    image: c360saascr.azurecr.io/risk-analysis-XXXX2:1123
    expose:
    - "5000"
    links:
      - elastic-search
    command: http://somerandom:8761/ risk-analysis-XXXX2 5000 risk-analysis-XXXX2-5000.log http://elastic-search:9200
    restart: on-failure


  elastic-search:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.3
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      discovery.type: single-node

  ngnix-server:
    image: nginx:1.15
    ports:
      - "5001:80"
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - risk-analysis-XXXX2


user nginx;
events { worker_connections 1024;}
http {
        server {
              listen 80;
              location / {
                proxy_pass http://risk-analysis-XXXX2:5000;
              }
        }
}
```

So above are the two files

1. XXXX are replaced to redact. So kindly ignore
2. nginx works on its own meaning when I call http://localhost:5001 it routes etc BUT
3. From risk-analysis-XXXX1 it is not able to call nginx. I have linked this to ngnix-server as you see also the URL I am trying to hit is http://ngnix-server:5001 with in  risk-analysis-XXXX1

Kindly help on #3. Why is it not hitting http://ngnix-server:5001? I get java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused.
I tried adding them in the same network but that did not work.
Note :- I am using docker-compose up --scale risk-analysis-XXXX2=3 to scale up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you map the port of 80 on your container to 5001 on the host right? If you then want to connect to the nginx-container over the same network, you should try to connect to port 80 (that' presumably the only "exposed" port that container has).

So this should work from your risk-analysis-XXXX1 container:

> http://ngnix-server:80

Comment: You are a star. It worked. Thank you very much. I am going to mark your answer as awesome

Comment: Ha no problem, glad I could help.

Comment: I have docker for desktop installed locally in my laptop where I tested your suggestion and it worked.  Now I copied over the nginx.conf and docker-compose.yml to amazonlinux (ec2). I have a docker installed there (followed - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html) ... Problem is the same docker-compose and ngnix.config gives java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused when calling http://ngnix-server:80... Any suggestions will help.

Comment: It is sorted now. in port 80 something else was running. So I changed it to 4000. All sorted now. Commenting here as this could be helpful to someone else